# How to connect multiple users in Embedded Derby Driver in java?

Tags: database, connection, derby, pool

I've created Java Application and set the derby driver to connect to my database ,
now connecting to embedded derby driver was successful but when multiple user try to connect to the database an error occur saying :

java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'C:/refletDBBackup/reflet' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3cc62c07, see the next exception for details.

my code to create database connection :

```
private static void createConnection()
{
    try
    {
        dbURL = "jdbc:derby:C:/refletDB/reflet;create=true;user=root;password=admin";
        Properties p = System.getProperties();
        p.setProperty("derby.system.home", "C:\\refletDB\\reflet");
        NetworkServerControl Serv = new NetworkServerControl();
        Serv.start(null);
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
        //Get a connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL); 

    }
    catch (Exception except)
    {
        except.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've did my research about the problem and found out that I need to create a connection pool in order to connect many users to the same connection .
Please any help ?
Thank you

Comment: **Read the tag-descriptions before adding.**

Comment: When Derby gives an error saying "see the next exception for details", you  can get those details by doing this: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain